# Having two views associated with one ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, observablecollection

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that has a Panorama control which displays all news articles on one panel and unread articles on another. Is it possible to be able to generate two views of the same data from a RangeObservableCollection? It currently works by having two separate ObservableCollections for these two lists.

Comment: Have you tried creating two properties (AllItems, UnreadItems) in your ViewModel, which perform a LINQ query on the single ObservableCollection and then bind your View to these two new properties?

Comment: Sounds like this is what i am trying to do. Though what are the AllItems and Unread properties? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: The AllItems and UnreadItems are potential names of properties in your ViewModel. Their type is ObservableCollection or similar (List<T>) and the body of the get would be a LINQ statement that includes a where clause, for example, for the UnreadItems, where unreadstatus = true. A code snippet isn't possible without knowning the classes involved, for example, I presume you have an Article class and you probably have some property in this class for the Articles read state.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll do that. Thanks